# Youtube Videos (1080p) Very Laggy

Tags: video, performance, youtube

Can't play 1080p videos on Youtube but they play flawlessly on Windows 7. Any suggestions/help? CPU: AMD Turion 64 x2 1.8GHz, 2GB Ram and ATI HD 3200.

Comment: Hi and welcome to askubuntu - please provide details (by editing your question) - what version of ubuntu, what is your graphics card (lspci | grep VGA), what graphics drivers you are using, how you have installed flash.

Comment: Updated, you have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Flash or HTML5?

- Flash - there may not be a solution. Flash for Windows is much more optimized than Flash for Linux.
- HTML5 - do you have graphics acceleration enabled for your graphics card? If you can play 1080p in MPlayer or VLC, then it should work with HTML5 on YouTube.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. It worked. Not super smooth but way better than flash. Thanks.

Comment: please mark the answer as solved by ticking the green v button. :)

Comment: @srunni how does one set your browser to use HTML5 vs Flash? Isnt that a function of youtube?

Comment: @n00b youtube.com/html5 and you can activate the player if it is not already. youtube then tries to use it first whenever possible.